# Toast pop up action require authorization

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```js
function greeting() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Toast tester", "Greeting", 7);
}
```

I tried running the toast script but I am asked to authorize the script which I did but still its not running the script

[This is the google sheet where i am running it from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Is3q.png)

It takes me to a Google confirmation page: [enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCbg0.png)

Comment: Did you register your application with the Google Developer Console? Unless you do that, Google will not allow your app to use any information from your Google account.

Comment: You are sharing your email publicly in one of your images.  That image is the authorization dialog you must click where it says "Continue only if you understand the risks"

Comment: @collab what do i do next

Comment: @cooper I am new at all this coding ish i understand the risk thanks for the update

Comment: So, it's running for you now?